# Custom CSS as module configuration option

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, module, css

I'm looking to add an option to a module that gives users the power to override CSS styling. The option in system.xml looks like this:

```
 <additional_css translate="label, comment">
  <label>Additional CSS:</label>
  <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
  <sort_order>2</sort_order>
  <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
  <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
  <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
 </additional_css>
```

Where I'm stuck is where to put the contents of this option. Ideally it is added to a CSS file that is loaded after the main module CSS is loaded. However I don't know if this is even possible. Anyone who has experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom `backend_model` for system field.

Add the following line 
`<backend_model>your_module/config_css</backend_model>` for `<additional_css translate="label, comment">` node.

And create new model:

```
class Your_Module_Model_Config_Css extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{
    protected function _afterSave()
    {
        if ($this->isValueChanged()) {
            try {
                $ioFile = new Varien_Io_File();
                $ioFile->open(array('path' => ***specify path to your css file***));
                $ioFile->filePutContent(***specify path to your css file*** . 'additional.css', $this->getValue());
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // TODO: add error msg
            }
        }
        return parent::_afterSave();
    }
}
```

*Don't forget change pathes to file and class name*

When you save config, content in `additional.css` will be changed as separated css file.

And you can add the separated css file by `addCss` or `addItem` methods in layout.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we're on the right track with your answer, however I'm still not able to get this to work and I think the path to the CSS file is causing the problem. In my module option I can see that the input is being saved but the assigned custom.css file is not being populated. This is how I configured the paths: $ioFile->open(array('path' => 'my_module/css'));
                $ioFile->filePutContent('my_module/css/' . 'custom.css', $this->getValue());

Comment: try to use full path for `open` and `filePutContent`.
`BP . DS . 'my_module' . DS . 'css'` for `open` call and
`BP . DS . 'my_module' . DS . 'css' . DS . 'custom.css'` for `filePutContent

Comment: It's not working. I'm also not sure whether I should define DS and BP first in the function but even declaring the full URL to the CSS won't make it work. I'm I missing something here?

Comment: Try to debug `_afterSave` method. And share your current system.xml section and new backend class.

Comment: <additional_css translate="label, comment">
                          <label>Additional CSS:</label>
                          <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                          <backend_model>frontpage/cssconfig</backend_model>
                          <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                          <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                          <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                          <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </additional_css>

Comment: <?php

class WWeb_Frontpage_Model_Cssconfig extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{
    public function _afterSave()
    {
        $cssDir = Mage::getBaseDir() . DS . 'skin' . DS . 'frontend' . DS . 'base' . DS . 'default' . 'vweb-categoryfrontpage' . DS . 'css';
        if ($this->isValueChanged()) {
            try {
                $ioFile = new Varien_Io_File();
                $ioFile->open(array('path' => $cssDir));
                $ioFile->filePutContent($cssDir . DS . 'custom.css', $this->getValue());
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // TODO: add error msg
etc..

Comment: Did you change value for your Custom css?
Because we have condition `if ($this->isValueChanged())` which check is value has been changed. Also let's try to add session msg in the method begin `Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addNotice('backend_model')` for indicatation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30787/discussion-between-badger-and-dmitryfurs).